# JPA - Json type postgres field mapping to different java beans based on record type

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jpa, mapping

```
@Entity
public class ConfigData<T> {
   String category;

   //Json field
   // Can I map this config to different types based on the category type? Is there a way in eclipselink JPA to achieve this?
   T config;
}
```

There is a table with JSON field. Each record correspond to a particular category. The JSON structure varies by category. Is there an option in JPA to map one field in my java entity to multiple beans?

```
category         config
Type1           {"key1": "value2"}
Type2           {"key2" : "valueee"}
Type1           {"key1": "value2222"}
```

I have the below Java bean which maps to the above json strings of each type.

```
public class Type1 {
   String key1;
}

public class Type2 {
   String key2;
}
```

I would like to access my entity as:

`ConfigData<Type1>` when the record is of category type Type1, should have the config bean Type1 and the likes.

Comment: Do you mean `@OneToMany`?

Comment: what is T representing? an entity? Problem insufficiently defined

Comment: Not OneToMany .. config is a Json type field in my postgres table. But it can contain different JSON structures like I have mentioned above Type1, Type2.